# How to add the below nginx ingress parameters/annotations in istio ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio, nginx-ingress, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

How can we update the below parameters in istio ingress gateway configurations.

1. ssl-redirect: "false"
2. force-ssl-redirect: "false"
3. proxy-read-timeout: "300"
4. allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
5. server-tokens: "False"
6. hide-headers: "X-Runtime,X-Powered-By"
7. proxy-body-size: "50m"

How can we migrate these nginx ingress controller changes to istio ingress gateway.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [the  Kubernetes controller for Elastic Load Balancers annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/guide/ingress/annotations/#annotations) section where you can conclude the **analogy** between `nginx ingress controller` and `istio ingress gateway` annotations.

The section has a curated and exhaustive list of all possible anntotions to use in your `istio ingress gateway`.

For instance you can use `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect` to enable SSLRedirect and specify the SSL port that redirects to, etc.

Comment: But, In this document, I don't see any annotations/parameters that I have mentioned above. We can see only some generic annotations in the above link.

Comment: The document has the full list of all possible annotations of `istio ingress gateway` you can check the analogy if not found, then it is not available for istio.